# Creating a login page using mysql java html and css

Tags: java, html, mysql

I have created the table that contains login details and write the program in java to process the information but i do not know how can I link the frontend file of html to java file

Comment: This is basic form + backend + SQL topic that can be found in any of the numerous tutorials all around the Internet

Comment: why you don't use Java server pages

Comment: thanx for the answer i've done it using jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use Spring? Spring boot? JavaEE?
I suggest to use Spring Boot.

Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within any of the following directories:

```
/META-INF/resources/
/resources/
/static/
/public/
```

So you can create a `public/` directory under `resources/` directory and put your static contents there. And they will be reached by: http://localhost:3000/koo.htm. (assuming the `server.port` is 3000)

You can customize these directories using `spring.resources.static-locations` in the `application.properties`.

You can continue read in https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot